# Collision in a 3D World

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, collision-detection, game-engine

I have recently been working on a small top-down grid-based 2D game. As part of an experiment I figured it to be fun to convert the 2D representation of an automatically generated level to 3D, similar to Wolfenstein 3D's style (as an example, I'm not actually using Raycasting).

Converting the grid to quads with textures is not that much of a problem, however, I'm kind of stuck on how to implement collision. I've been browsing the Internet for articles for 2 days now but none has really given me a good starting point in how to prepare my 3D world for collision and how to actually implement it.

Does anyone know any good articles for me to read, or maybe even care to write a small excerpt of steps I have to go through?

I'm writing the game in XNA/C#, however, any type of resource you might know is welcome (be it C++ or whatever else).

Comment: How are you implementing collision-detection in 2D?

Comment: in xna its probably just changing `BoundingCircle`s to `BoundingSphere`s

Comment: Real quick 'n dirty bounding box check, I haven't even added a form of broad-phase culling. I plan on extending the grid to also allow diagonal walls etcetera as I want to use that in the 3D representation.

Comment: Hmm, I think I should have posted this in gamedev instead.

Comment: You can flag for moderator attention and ask for it to be migrated to gamedev if you think it best? Its better to ask for mods to do it that to completely recreate the same question on the other site

Comment: I'll see what happens here, I can always let it be moved later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way Wolfenstein 3D (and similar) handle collision detection is simple: the map is a uniform square cells map. Wolf3d subdivided the cells in (if memory serves me correctly) 64x64 sub units to allow the player to gracefully glide through the maze. For collision detection it   is sufficient to check the position of the player to cells of the grid, if the cell contains a blocking obstacle (table, wall, dog, door): block otherwise: move on.

If you are looking for diagonals and other random polygons, have a look at articles on Portal engines. The step from Wolf3D cells to Doom/Quake BSP Trees is a big one but there are quite a few good [articles by Jacco Bikker at the bottom of the Flipcode archives](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/articles.shtml) **Read those!**